# API Document _ How to change the format of Models for each API?

Tags: api, swagger, models

I am writing API Document by Swagger.
I defined the Response format is:

```
definitions:
 ResponseFormat:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
    msg:
      type: string
      description: Error or success message
    data:
      type: object
```

Then, for each API, the format of data (object) will change. How can I change it.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the format of data will change"?

Comment: My “data” in ResponeFormat is object type.
Example: I want in API_0, response code is
{
  "name": “string”
    "msg": "string",
    "data": {\n
 “number”: “int64”
}  }
In API_1, response code is
{
  "name": “string”
    "msg": "string",\n
    "data": {\n
 “gender”: “boolean”
 “fullName”: “string”
}  }
Format of “data” changed. Can we do that?